# How to split on every word and white space?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string, split

I'm trying to split simple contentText(from a span element) with white spaces but for some reason it doesn't split all white spaces.

My algorithm is working properly with the other elements like input texts. Did some research for hours now but I couldn't find the result that I need.

```
var list_topic = table.find('.list_topic')[0].textContent;
var check_topic = list_topic.split(" ");
console.log(check_topic);
```

The code above returns:

```
["    ","word ","word    ","word","  ","word "]
```

#### Desired Output"

````
["","","","","","word","","word","","","","","word","","","","word",""]```
````

Comment: please add `list_topic` as well.

Comment: A clear problem statement includes the _input_ (the original string), the code, and _the desired output_.  You've got the code and the desired output, but we can't help without the _input_.

Comment: Split on `/\s/g` or manually detect white-space.

Comment: @NinaScholz `  word  word  word   word ` is the list_topic, if you join the array back together, delimited with a space.

Comment: `/\s+/g` to split on one or more spaces throughout the string.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, `split` is always *global*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take a regular expression which looks for white space.

```js
var string = '    word  word word      \nword';

console.log(string.split(/\s/));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var check_topic = list_topic.split("");
for (var i = 0; i < check_topic) {
    if (check_topic[i] == " ") {
        check_topic[i] = "";
    } else if (check_topic[i-1] != "") {
        check_topic[i-1] += check_topic[i];
        check_topic.splice(i,1);
    }
}
```

This takes a string and splits it by every single character. If it's whitespace, then it removes it and makes it "" instead of " ". Then, if it's not, AND the last one in the array isn't, it joins the 2. So, something like word would look like this:

```
[" ", "w","o","r","d"]
["", "w","o","r","d"]
["", "wo","r","d"]
["", "wor","d"]
["", "word"]
```